# mobile website - iphone div position

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari, positioning, html

I am developing a mobile website. An issue im running into is positioning some divs.
(testing on iphone 4 atm)
http://rerender.tv/phoenix/m

I have a couple of divs that are suppose to be placed at the right of the viewport (right top and right bottom)
the divs are set with

```
position:absolute;
right: 3%;
top: 3%;
```

But on the iphone it looks like those divs get placed towards the middle.

Also on the subpages, theres a div container that holds content with the width set to 95%, but the content (text) only goes half way in the viewport.
http://rerender.tv/phoenix/m/about.html

Not sure what the issue here is but it looks like the page width is not scaling to the full size of the viewport. Although the meta tag is declaring the scaling at 1 and the size of the viewport to be device content.

Searched around, couldnt find anything. But i think im just overlooking something.
Help?
thanks

Comment: solved. atm, changed device width to 640.